# Зачем нужен extern, если без него все работает?

Tags: c, память

`prog_1.c:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 314;
int *func_1(void)
{
    printf("%s : a = %d, &a = %p\n", __func__, a, (void *) &a);
    return &a;
}
```

`prog_2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* func_1(void);
int a;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s : a = %d, &a = %p\n", __func__, a, (void *) &a);
    func_1();
    return 0;
}
```

`Результат:`

```
main : a = 314, &a = 0x23010
func_1 : a = 314, &a = 0x23010
```

Таким образом, не используя `extern` объявление переменной `a` в `prog_1.c`, возможно к ней обращаться в `prog_2.c`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваша программа некорректна с точки зрения языка С, ибо она содержит множественное определение переменной `a`.

Ваша программа компилируется только благодаря нестандартному расширению вашего компилятора. Другим словами, "дыра" в используемом вами компиляторе (или его настройки) позволяет этому коду "проскользнуть" без генерации диагностического сообщения. В рамках этого расширения, оба определения переменной `a` считаются ссылающимися на один и тот же объект. Что вы и наблюдаете.

Более педантичный в этом отношении компилятор укажет вам на двойное определение переменной `a`. Я не знаю, есть ли способ заставить, скажем, GCC генерировать диагностическое сообщение в таких случаях, но, например, [Tiny C](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc) педантично отлавливает такие нарушения.

---

То, что вы наблюдаете - известное популярное расширения языка С, не являющееся, однако, стандартным поведением. Так вели себя компиляторы С для платформы Unix еще в 70-х годах. Однако уже в K&R C было принято решение отказаться от юниксовской модели объявлений/определений, и был сделан переход к более строгому подходу, требующему единственного определения. Стандартный С еще немножко поменял модель объявлений/определений языка, но сохранил требование единственного определения.

В документе [Rationale for International Standard — Programming Languages — C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (раздел "6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers") довольно детально описывается развитие моделей объявлений/определений в языке С. Ваша программа, в терминологии этого документа, соответствует "Relaxed Ref/Def" или "Initializer Ref/Def" модели, в то время как стандартный С придерживается комбинации "Strict Ref/Def" модели (лишь с непринципиальной примесью элементов "Initializer Ref/Def" модели).

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то говоря, не факт, что работает. А если работает - что работает правильно.

Например, Watcom предупреждает, что он игнорирует переопределение переменной, и собирает так, что выводит - в зависимости от того, делать

```
wcl386 prog_1.c prog_2.c
```

или

```
wcl386 prog_2.c prog_1.c
```

значение `a` 314 или 0. Меня такое "работает" никак устроить не может. Претензии к компилятору предъявить тоже нельзя: согласно стандарту, так поступать нельзя.

А если еще и определить `a` в обоих файлах не по умолчанию, а дать точные значения - то уже и тот же Visual C++ 2015 не будет компилировать (вернее, линковать).

Короче, не надо полагаться на то, что "и так сойдет" :)